# How can I find a special character in my string and store all value after this character in a variable

Tags: php

I am trying to find special character `$@` from my string and trying to store all value after these special in a variable but I could not do this task. How do I find this `$@` special character in my whole string and store all value after this special charecter in a variable. My string is:

```
 92~SAPL/1200/2012~2~LAXMAN SINGH AND OTHERS~SHANKER SINGH AND OTHERS~D~
 2014-04-10~09:31:13
 07/04/2014|93~SAPL/275/1998~1~RAM SWAROOP AND OTHERS~BABU RAM AND OTHERS~D~
 2014-04-10~09:31:13 07/04/2014|94~FAFOD/52/2013~3~RAM KUMAR PANDEY~RAJENDRA PANDEY AND
 ANOTHER~D~2014-04-10~09:31:13 07/04/2014$@2014-04-10~2014-04-09
```

Comment: `echo substr($string, strpos($string, '$@') + 1);`

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
$string = "Your Entire String";
$explodedString = explode('$@', $string);

if(count($explodedString) > 1) {
   unset($explodedString[0]);
   $returnString = count($explodedString) > 1 ? $explodedString : $explodedString[0];
} else {
   $returnString = null;
}

if(is_array($returnString)) {
   //if you want to divide the string only to the first occurrence of $@ leave the below line as is else comment it out
   $returnString = implode('', $returnString);
}

echo $returnString;
```